# Java Annotation Processing Messager API Messages not displayed

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, annotation-processing

I have some Interfaces with custom annotations for adding metadata. In specific those interfaces represent tables in a database and the annotations say what table the interface should be mapped to and what columns the properties are.

I use annotation processing to generate code files that do some work such as loading the data from the database etc. I also have a `ValidationProcessor` that should validate the interfaces if all needed metadata are available and so on. When I validate the annotations I want to display warning and errors so that it is clear what is not correct and where that problem occurs.

For printing the messages I use the Messager API. Here is the code I use where `kind` is e.g. `Kind.ERROR`, msg is the message and element is the element on which the error occured (it is a Type that implements the `Element` interface).

```
processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(kind, msg, element, null, null);
```

According to my internet research (including similar articles on stackoverflow) this should be the way to correctly display messages. Nevertheless the messages are not display.

My question is, does anyone have an idea what could be wrong?

Comment: You have two annotation processors that process the same annotation?  Are you sure that the validation processor is being invoked at all?

Comment: Yes it is invoked. And yes, there are more than one Processor for an annotation and both are invoked. Actually, there is only one big processor, that listens for all annotations and splits them up afterwards. (I didn't write it that way, the code was written before my time in the company. I also don't think I get the time to rewrite everthing). Do you think this could cause the problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you create messages is correct, though you could just use

```
printMessage(kind, msg, element);
```

if you don't want to display messages on annotations or annotation values. When overriding the processor's `init` method, make sure to call `super.init(processingEnv)` so it is set up correctly.

It sounds like the processor fails due some error in the execution. The processor will fail silently if there is an uncatched exception and then it won't display any messages. To debug an annotation processor activate the *error log* view:

[image: Window > Show View > Error Log]

In this view you should see every message by the *messager* as well as any uncatched exceptions thrown by the processor. The stack trace should help you to locate the error.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip I will take a look at it. Currently I just accepted it that it doesn't work... but maybe that could solve the problem.

Comment: After some time of leaving the problem as it was I finially got time to fix it. In the error log I see all errors, warnings I print but only if a file contains at least one error (which I mark via the printMessage(Kind.ERROR,... method) all the errors and warnings for that file are displayed in the editor. Do you know why only errors are shown? When only warnigns are printed for a class they only show up in the error log view. As long as a file does not contain any error, the warnings wont show up in the editor (Again, in the error log they are always visible).

Comment: @mvieghofer I have no idea. Sounds like it could be a bug in eclipse.

Comment: Ok thanks. Since you led me in the right direction, I'll mark your answer as correct.